# Need Regex Pattern: Can't start w num; No special characters except underscore and hyphen; allows characters/nums

Tags: regex

Closest I've gotten: `^[-_[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

That still allows the string to start with numbers.  Apologies for asking such question when there are resources everywhere.  I just need something fast and have problems figuring out RegEx.

Valid input examples: `Account-Numbers_2010 | NewMoney | test_data | a1B2-c3_d4_5e-6f`

Invalid input examples: `2010_Account_Numbers | New$Money | %test*data | 1aB2`

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ < Can be very helpful for figuring this stuff out.

Comment: Is this strictly 7-bit ASCII data?

Comment: Which language are you using this in?

Comment: It's being used in a C# project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should make it:

```
"^[A-Za-z_-][A-Za-z0-9_-]*$"
```

`[A-Za-z_-]` means a letter or underscore or hyphen
`[A-Za-z0-9_-]*` is the same, but allows numbers too

So this will allow letters, underscores, hyphens, and numbers, but no numbers at the start.

Looking at your valid input example `Account-Numbers_2010 | NewMoney | test_data | a1B2-c3_d4_5e-6f`, you may want to also allow spaces and `|`. This one allows them:

```
"^[A-Za-z_ |-][A-Za-z0-9_ |-]*$"
```

This one correctly matches `Account-Numbers_2010 | NewMoney | test_data | a1B2-c3_d4_5e-6f` and not `2010_Account_Numbers | New$Money | %test*data | 1aB2`.

Answer (score 5):

You need 2 parts to the regex.  The first character, and then the rest.

```
^[a-zA-Z_-][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$
```

This says:

> Start with any character from `a-z` or `A-Z` or `_` or `-`.  And then follow that by any alphanumeric character or `_` or `-`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-z0-9_-]){0,}
```