# Restrict users from inserting special character except underscore

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I want to restrict users from

1. inserting special characters **except ' _ ' underscore**
2. inserting Capitol Letters
3. inserting first value as number
4. inserting first value as special character
5. inserting `spaces`

in the textbox of `<input>`

I tried the below snippet but it didn't give me results for `1` & `4`.

```js
$(function() { 
$('.alphaonly').on('input', function() { 
$(this).val(function(i, val) { 
return val.replace(/^\d|[A-Z\s]+/g, ''); 
}); 
}); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<input name="lorem" class="alphaonly">
```

Comment: can you edit your question on what are the condition you want to achieve..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need Regex Pattern: Can't start w num; No special characters except underscore and hyphen; allows characters/nums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783454/need-regex-pattern-cant-start-w-num-no-special-characters-except-underscore-a)

Comment: @ShadowFiend I edited the question.

Comment: @MKJain try my answer. I think i've got it..

Comment: @ShadowFiend please update your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {     
var haveFirst = false;
$('.alphaonly').on('keypress', function (event) {
  if( $(this).val().length === 0 ) {
     haveFirst = false;
  }
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9_]+$");
var first = new RegExp("^[a-z]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if(!first.test(key) && haveFirst == false){
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}else if(regex.test(key)){
   haveFirst = true;
}
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
}); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<input name="lorem" class="alphaonly">
```

Comment: It helped me somewhere, but I also don't want '_' as the first character!

Comment: @MKJain w8 i edit my answer.. i forgot to add false again when input box is empty.

Comment: And it also checks other inputs, I only want to check having class `alphaonly`.

Comment: @MKJain if you dont want to effect other inputs you have lot options. Example: 1st just give different class on others or give different class on this special input

Comment: @MKJain i've got it.

Comment: Thank you for investing time in my question! I solved my question with https://stackoverflow.com/a/46293545/8618783

Comment: @MKJain you should give him upvote he just give your answer of what u achieve

Comment: @MukhdelgerTumenbayar , sorry to say I need atlesa 15 reputation to upvote!

Comment: Hi @ShadowFiend Thank you for this post. but i need regex to restrict all special as well as alphabets except one (comma with multiple occurrences). This regex (/[^0-9.]/g) works for me, but it allows only one comma. I need multiple occurrences of comma. could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://regex101.com/r/3mtS4t/1

This regex ^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$  will allow only name with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Here this i use this for some kind for utf-8

```
$("YourClassorIdOfInputOrTextField").bind("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.charCode!=0) {
             var regex = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9 _]");

        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

    }
});
```

This will achieve what you seek stranger

Comment: As you mention from previous post (not deleted). first letter must be lowercase. You should able to do it with javascript can you tell me what you exactly seek?

Comment: <script> 
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    if (event.charCode!=0) {
        var regex = new RegExp("[^A-Za-z0-9]");

        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

    }
}); 
</script>

Comment: and in `input` ==> onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"

Comment: Thank you for investing time in my question! I solved my question with https://stackoverflow.com/a/46293545/8618783

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple replacement for your function based on regular expressions:

```
function blockSpecialChar(e) {
    return /[^A-Za-z0-9._]/.test(e);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RajKumarDubey/ko29twoh/

Comment: It helped me somewhere, but I also don't want '_' as the first & last character!

Comment: Thank you for investing time in my question! I solved my question with https://stackoverflow.com/a/46293545/8618783